# Configure a Java Socket to fail-fast on disconnect?

Tags: java, exception, sockets, networking

I have a listening port on my server that I'm connecting to using a Java class and the `Socket` interface, i.e.

```
Socket mySocket = new Socket(host,port);
```

I then grab an `OutputStream`, decorate with a `PrintWriter` in autoflush mode and I'm laughing - except if the listening port closes. Then I get

```
tcp4       0      0  *.9999                 *.*                    LISTEN
tcp        0      0  127.0.0.1.45737        127.0.0.1.9999         CLOSE_WAIT
```

and I can't seem to detect the problem in the program - I've tried using the `isConnected()` method on the socket but it doesn't seem to know that the connection is closed.

I want to be aware of the problem the next time I try and write to the Socket so that I can try and reconnect and report the issue.

Any advice please?

Thanks all

Comment: The isConnected() method tells you whether you ever connected this Socket. It doesn't tell you about the state of the connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a short timeout?

Does `isOutputShutdown()` not get you what you want?

You could always build a `SocketWatcher` class that spins up in its own `Thread` and repeatedly tries to write empty strings to the `Socket` until that raises a `SocketClosedException`.

Comment: No, isOutputShutdown() doesn't give him what he wants, and neither does a short timeout or an attempt to get a SocketClosedException, which doesn't even exist. You are confusing the state of the Socket withe the state of the connection. -1

Answer (score 0):

The only reliable way to detect a broken connection in TCP is to write to it, which will eventually cause a 'connection reset' IOException. However due to buffering it won't happen on the first write after the disconnection,p but on a subsequent write. You can't do anything about this.

Answer (score -2):

Set a different thread to reading from the socket.  It will block until the socket is closed, and then an exception will be thrown.  Catch that exception to detect the close immediately.

Comment: It is possible for a TCP connection fail in a way that cannot be detected by a read.